# How do I get a mandatory named parameter in sub MAIN?

Tags: raku

This is the best I could get:

```
sub MAIN(Int :p($parm)!)
{
  say "* parm=", $parm;
}
```

But:

```
$ raku test-par.raku
Usage:
  test-par.raku -p[=Int]
```

It says the parameter is optional!
And indeed it is:

```
 $ raku test-par.raku -p
 * parm=True
```

So, what gives ?

Comment: `-p` is a boolean, and boolean `True` is an `Int` (and thus passes the `Int` type constraint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Bool` also happens to be an `Int`:

```
$ raku -e 'say True.Int'
1

$ raku -e 'say True ~~ Int'
True
```

Because `-p` is a `Bool` it is also an `Int`:

```
$ raku -e 'sub MAIN(Int :p($param)) { say $param.raku; say $param ~~ Int; say $param.Int }' -p=42
IntStr.new(42, "42")
True
42

$ raku -e 'sub MAIN(Int :p($param)) { say $param.raku; say $param ~~ Int; say $param.Int }' -p
Bool::True
True
1

$ raku -e 'sub MAIN(Int :p($param)) { say $param.raku; say $param ~~ Int; say $param.Int }' --/p
Bool::False
True
0
```

The parameter is still optional; `-p` is just being treated (arguably unintuitively) like `-p=1`. To actually enforce the requested constraint would unfortunately require adding an additional filter:

```
$ raku -e 'sub MAIN(Int :p($param) where * !~~ Bool) { say $param.raku; say $param ~~ Int; say $param.Int }' --p=1
IntStr.new(1, "1")
True
1

$ raku -e 'sub MAIN(Int :p($param) where * !~~ Bool) { say $param.raku; say $param ~~ Int; say $param.Int }' -p
Usage:
  -e '...' [-p[=Int where { ... }]]
```

Comment: I understand that a Bool is an Int, and that's ok by me, but what I find strange is that one letters parameters are also considered to be optional parameters ... I don't think that is made explicitly clear in the documentation in https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli ... also, I don't think making one parameters being optional a good choice, AFAIK that's not usual

Comment: The optionality of the parameter is the same `-p`/`--p`/`-param`/`--param`. But by saying saying `-p`/`--p`/`-param`/`--param` with no value specifically against an `Int` type constraint you are supplying the value `1`

Comment: I tested here now `sub MAIN(Int :$parm)` and it's true they're optional ... but like I said before, I don't think it's a good design choice ... anyway, your answer is correct

Comment: Named parameters are always optional unless you explicitly declare it so, regardless of if its in `sub MAIN` or any other non-CLI related sub. So the design is at least consistent with the rest of the language.

Answer (score 2):

As some other questions have said `True` is an `Enum` with value of `1` so it's and `Int` if you want to ensure the `-p` is always called with a value you can use the [ARGS-TO-CAPTURE](https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli#sub_ARGS-TO-CAPTURE) function to check the incoming arguments *before* they are passed to main. Something like :

```
sub ARGS-TO-CAPTURE(&main, @args) {
    if none(@args) ~~ /"-p=" \d+/ { 
        say $*USAGE; 
        exit;
    } 
    &*ARGS-TO-CAPTURE(&main,@args)
}
```

Here we check that at least one of the arguments is `-p` and it has also got an integer value. You can also override the `$*USAGE` value by adding the [GENERATE-USAGE](https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli#sub_GENERATE-USAGE) sub if you want to change how it displays `-p` in the output.

Comment: Note that if you want either `-p` or `--param` you'll of course need to update the regex a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for the answers and comments.

For my specific whims, this is the best I could come to:

```
use v6;

use Getopt::Long;

get-options("p|port=i" => my $port);

sub MAIN
{
  # for the case that no args were passed
  without $port { say "*** error, missing args"; exit }

  say "*** port=$port"
}
```

As far as I can see, it handles short and long options, and makes the options mandatory.